# How to check the 'verify' setting in Python's requests using RequestBin or similar

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I'm trying to make a `requests` session in which the `verify` keyword argument of each request is set to `False` (rather than its default value, `True`). I've tried the following (in Python 3):

```
import requests, time

requestbin_URL = 'http://requestb.in/1nsaz9y1'      # For testing only; remains usable for 48 hours

class DebugSession(requests.Session):
    def __init__(self, verify=False):
        super().__init__()
        self.verify = verify

with DebugSession() as s:
    response = s.post(requestbin_URL, data={"time" : time.time()})
```

A request seems to have been made, as seen from http://requestb.in/1nsaz9y1?inspect:

[image]

The only problem is that I don't see how I can check whether setting `verify` was successful or not from the information given (namely, headers and form/post parameters). How can I check this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You are making a request to an HTTP URL where `verify=False` does not have any significance. Try replacing the URL with the ones having misconfigured certifications from [badssl.com](https://badssl.com/) (for example, https://expired.badssl.com/). If you are able to connect, it means the certificate isn't being verified.